# Generate .NET Client from Swagger

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger-codegen

What tool can I use to generate a .NET Client to consume from a Swagger definition?

For example, I started trying NSwag Studio and I would like to be able to generate the code to look like the Repository classes I am used to create.

Note to the voters wishing to delete the question: the answers and comments of the question are useful for readers, so deletion is not a good idea.
As SO doesn’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, the question should stay closed or (even better) consider to migrate to http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Visual Studio (2017) has this functionality built in:  Right-click project => Add => REST Api Client...

Comment: It uses AutoRest, right?

Comment: No idea, unfortunately.

Comment: I tried it a few months ago but I wasn't really convinced.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure/autorest

Comment: @KennethK. - wont work if you API spec is "openapi": "3.0.1"

Comment: This is a great tool and worked for me -> https://editor.swagger.io/

Comment: Consider to migrate to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you don't feel like messing with the commandline you can choose to install the [Visual Studio Extension Unchase.OpenAPI.Connectedservice](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=unchase.unchaseOpenAPIConnectedService). Then right-click on your project and choose Add->Service reference (or connected service).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use the `swagger-codegen` tool from the swagger project. It produces C# files that use

- `RestClient` for the HTTP calls
- `Newtonsoft.Json` for json marshalling
- .NET `DataContract` for the models.

You can either download the [cli app](https://swagger.io/tools/swagger-codegen/download/) or use the  [online editor](https://editor.swagger.io). The petstore example models look like this:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace IO.Swagger.Model {

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [DataContract]
    public class Order {
      /// <summary>
      /// Gets or Sets Id
      /// </summary>
      [DataMember(Name="id", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
      public long? Id { get; set; }

      /// <summary>
      /// Gets or Sets PetId
      /// </summary>
      [DataMember(Name="petId", EmitDefaultValue=false)]
      [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "petId")]
      public long? PetId { get; set; }
 .... snip ....
}
```

Answer (score 21):

You may want to try OpenAPI Generator (https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator), which supports both OpenAPI spec v2 and v3. (OpenAPI spec v2 was formerly known as Swagger spec v2)

There are 3 different C# client generators:

- csharp
- csharp-netcore
- csharp-dotnet2

The project also includes 2 C# server generators: csharp-nancyfx, aspnetcore

If you need help, please open an issue in the Github repo.

Disclosure: I'm the top contributor to both OpenAPI Generator and Swagger Codegen.

Comment: Hi,
the generator works also as the maven generator for java, producing the code directly during the build?
Or you have to produce the code and then export to your project?
Thank you

Comment: You can use the openapi-generator maven plugin: https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/integration.md

Comment: How can I integrate the maven plugin into .Net Core project?

Comment: If it's a .net core project, what about using the cake addin instead? https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/integration.md#cake-addin